# full calender not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, rendering, fullcalendar

hi i'm working on [full calender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) I have a problem displaying the values in **Mozilla Firefox**. where as in **Chrome** the code **works perfectly**.

i'm fetching the value from database and displaying it, but as of now i'm using the following **static values** as input.

```
var abc = new Array();
abc =[{AddedNew: false,allDay: false,end: "Mon May 13 2013 7:30:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)",getA_ID: "72",id: "[_fc1_3 ",start: "Mon May 13 2013 6:30:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)",title: "mon"}];
```

**Chrome Screenshoot** - Using static values
[image]

**Firefox Screenshoot** - Using static values
[image]

**The values in console are correct in Chrome and Firefox**

I don't know where i'm going wrong or its a problem with Firefox.

Comment: Did you try the example given in the site on firefox? Just use the sample array given in the document and check it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input date strings for the calendar have not a standard format (according to [plugin's documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)):

```
'Mon May 13 2013 7:30:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)' (your format)
'Mon, 13 May 2013 7:30:00 GMT' (expected format)
```

Because I am not an expert for regular expressions, can only propose you the following (working) fix:

```js
var abc = [{AddedNew: false,allDay: false,end: "Mon May 13 2013 7:30:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)",getA_ID: "72",id: "[_fc1_3 ",start: "Mon May 13 2013 6:30:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)",title: "mon"}];
abc.map(function(item){
    var t = item.end.split(' ');
    item.end = [t[0]+',', t[2], t[1], t[3], t[4], t[5]].join(' ');
    t = item.start.split(' ');
    item.start = [t[0]+',', t[2], t[1], t[3], t[4], t[5]].join(' ');
    return item;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/z6xCr/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the events i'm fetching, this works for an AJAX call:
You can compare with yours,

```
<event allDay="false" editable="true" end="Mon May 13 2013 13:00:00 GMT+0100" id="11"   start="Mon May 13 2013 08:00:00 GMT+0100" title="te3ste"/>

<event allDay="false" editable="true" end="Mon May 13 2013 19:00:00 GMT+0100" id="12" start="Mon May 13 2013 14:00:00 GMT+0100" title="hhhhh"/>

<event allDay="false" editable="true" end="Mon May 13 2013 17:00:00 GMT+0100" id="13" start="Mon May 13 2013 15:00:00 GMT+0100" title="hjhj"/>
```

Comment: +1. Hi Henrique, tested the data you provided and it works good. So it would be better solution, if Yashee could somehow reformat his dates from "`Mon May 13 2013 7:30:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)`" to "`Mon May 13 2013 7:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`" --- only to add the plus sign after GMT, it works!

Comment: I'm happy i could help :). I am also on a learning quest about Fullcalendar and i have passed the fase where your in. If you need any more help please just ask ;).

Comment: Thanks Henrique, I am not using the calendar on my site, only was a bit curious about how does it work ;-) And so i guess it would be much simpler solution, if Yashhy would modify his dates before adding to a database. In PHP it's much simpler than in javascript, like: `$s = 'Mon May 13 2013 7:30:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)'; $s[strpos($s,'GMT')+3]='+';` Well, have a good time